# Spring RequestMapping only maps one RequestParameter

Tags: spring-mvc

Hi i have an endpoint with multiple Request Parameters

```
@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, value = "/somepath")
SomeDTO getSomething(
@ApiParam(value = "Some filter one", required = true) @RequestParam(required = false, value = "propertyId") String propertyId,
@ApiParam(value = "Some filter two", required = false) @RequestParam(required = false, value = "otherPropertyId") String otherPropertyId){
...
}
```

When i invoke endpoint with only one parameter like

```
wget http://localhost:8085/somepath?propertyId=3016868
```

I see in the logs that propertyId is 3016868.

But when i use both parameters like

```
wget http://localhost:8085/somepath?propertyId=3016868&otherPropertyId=3016867
```

I see in the logs that propertyId is 3016868 but otherPropertyId is null

When i switch the paramters

```
wget http://localhost:8085/somepath?otherPropertyId=3016868&propertyId=3016867
```

I see in the logs that otherPropertyId is 3016868 but propertyId is null

So it seems to me that only first parameter is mapped. Has anyone a clue why ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that you have to put the url in Qutation Marks. Then all parameters are mapped. Its not a Spring Problem